# How to create different ItemsPanelTemplate for a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing an IM program on Windows Phone 8. And I am currently dealing with the UI for chatting. 
I want to create a `ListBox` that holds all the "chat bubbles" (like those in iPhone). The incoming messages appear on the left-hand side, and outgoing messages on the right-hand side. Like this:

[image]

So obviously, I need to set differnt **alignment** for each item.

I was trying to solve this by wrapping the bubble in a large `Grid` that expands all the space in the `ItemsPanel`, and align the chat bubble to the right (the parent of the chat bubble is the large `Grid`). But that didn't work because a grid in `ItemsPanel` won't fill up all the spaces automatically. And then I went for searching "*how to fill up all spaces in ItemsPanel*" and no luck.

So, I think the only way to do this is to set different `ItemsPanelTemplate` for each ItemsPanel, to either "Right" or "Left".

Please, help me.. Thank you!

So how do you create a selector for different `ItemsPanelTemplate`?

Comment: If you have a property that distinguishes each item type, you can use a data trigger on that property value. You could have one trigger set left alignment, and another one set right alignment

Comment: I tried. But style triggers are no longer available in Windows Phone 7 or 8 apps.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to customize the itemContainer :

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnswer}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

In case you dont have style triggers, you can use binding and a bool to HorizontalAlignment  converter :

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding IsAnswer,Converter={StaticResource AlignmentConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, because style triggers are not available in Windows Phone. Is there any equivalence or alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0):

you only need 2 View's for your messages  aka `DataTemplate`

one for `MyMsg` and one for `Answer`  both inhire from the Message class or interface (your decision) lets call it `Msg`

so you can set your `ItemsSource` to `List<Msg>` or `ObservableCollection<Msg>` and you are done