# How to change the visible property of the text box from the view model ( WPF, MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

I am a beginner here in WPF and MVVM. I have certain controls on a window in my project. For example, I have a text box in my window. I am using MVVM Pattern and here I want to change the visible property of the text box from the view model. 
One other thing is that, I want to change the visibility of the text box from the viewmodel based on some conditions.

Well, I googled it and google throws me some suggestions which were all different solutions and I'm in a total confusion.

Guess some one can help me figure this out.

I know this would be a piece of cake for the WPF MVVM Experts, but since I am trying to learn this stuff I require some code as examples.

Thanks

Comment: This question is similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400583/how-to-set-different-horizontalalignment-to-listboxitems/15401763#15401763

Comment: I believe you need VisibilityToBooleanConverter, do search for it

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Indeed there are multiple ways to implement such a functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is MVVM, you don't want to *change the visibility of the textbox* you actually want to *disable* some *option*.. Then - whether that option is enabled or disabled should reflect on the visibility of your Textbox.

So basically you want a `Property` in the ViewModel such as:

```
public bool CanMyPropertyBeChanged {get; set;}
```

Which you can change (of course you should probably [implement INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) if you haven't already)...
And bind the visibility of the Textbox to this property, via a Converter:

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding CanMyPropertyBeChanged, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}" />
```

You can use the built-in **[BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx)** for this:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />
```

Comment: Hi,

What exactly I need is :

I have a text box A and text box B. When the focus from the textbox A is lost, (Condition) I need to check whether the textbox A is empty and if empty, I need to hide the textbox B.

we can put a command on the LostFocus event of textbox A using interaction triggers to achieve the event handling in textbox A, but how can I get the above Condition to a Command in the viewmodel. 

Thanks

Comment: My solution will work for this case: Both TextBoxA and TextboxB are binded to properties in the VM. Lets call them PropertyA and PropertyB respectively. Either on the LostFocus of TextBoxA (as a Command) **or** when PropertyA changes (in the setter of PropertyA) you set the `CanMyPropertyBeChanged` based on whether PropertyA is empty or not. Of course, TextboxB's visibility is binded to the `CanMyPropertyBeChanged` property

Comment: Ahem, change notification.

Answer (score 2):

In you XAML file add the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
<Window.Resources>
```

On your textbox add:

```
<TextBox .... Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleBoolean, Converter={StaticResourcebooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

In your viewmodel add the IsVisibleBoolean property:

```
public bool IsVisibleBoolean 
{
    get; set;
}
```

Comment: Your property has no change notification, so this won't work but for once.  Also, you should probably go read the framework guidelines.

Comment: @Will It is also missing the rest of the code where you set the data context of the view, and the rest of the properties for the text box and many other things, but it is meant to be an example, not a running piece of code. Your comments are not really constructive.

Comment: I used the followin gto make it work <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

Answer (score 1):

you can do it multiple way

### first of all you could bind it directly

**XAML**

```
<TextBox  Visibility="{Binding myVisibility}"/>
```

**VM Property**

```
public Visibility myVisibility
    {
        get { return Visibility.Hidden; }
    }
```

### but you could also use a Converter (the recommended way)

**XAML**

```
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourNamespace">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox  Visibility="{Binding myVisibility,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"/>
```

**VM Property**

```
public bool myVisibility
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
```

**BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool),typeof(Visibility))]
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public bool IsReversed { get; set; }
    public bool UseHidden { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (this.IsReversed)
        {
            val = !val;
        }
        if (val)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return this.UseHidden ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: the convert is a part of the framework now, so there isn't any need.  Your properties also lack change notification.

Comment: @Will it is just a simple example ... and he told he is new in wpf mvvm ... so please don't try to be smart ;o)