# Case statments in XAML with DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

## I want to implement a listbox that displays a different DataTemplate depending on a property in its bound data.

I have a class called `Notification` that can hold different types of notifications all 
dependent solely on the data it is holding as opposed to having separate classes for each item.

```
 public class Notification : Interfaces.IListable
{
    Cache.NotificationType _type;
    public Cache.NotificationType Type
    {
        get {return _type;}
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case Cache.NotificationType.DocumentAnnouncment:
                    this.FriendlyType = "Document Announcment";
                    break;
                case Cache.NotificationType.DocumentComment:
                    this.FriendlyType = "Document Comment";
                    break;
                case Cache.NotificationType.FileTransfer:
                    this.FriendlyType = "File Transfer Progress";
                    break;
                case Cache.NotificationType.GeneralAnnouncment:
                    this.FriendlyType = "Special Announcment";
                    break;
                case Cache.NotificationType.MeetingAnnouncment:
                    this.FriendlyType = "Meeting Announcment";
                    break;
                case Cache.NotificationType.MeetingComment:
                    this.FriendlyType = "Meeting Comment";
                    break;

            }

            _type = value;
        }
    }
```

The main idea here is that I want to have a different data template depending on what the `FriendlyType` property is.

So for future readability purposes I will restate my question more specifically.

**How can I implement a different data template for a list box depending on the `Notification.FriendlyType` my listbox is showing?**

Comment: I gave you an answer to your question, but as a side note, you should always throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for `default:` when switching on an enumeration, just in case it is out of range...

Comment: m-y's answer below should work. An alternative solution would be to create derived classes of Notification e.g. DocumentAnnouncementNotification ... DocumentCommentNotification etc. You can then create DataTemplates like in m-y's answer, but set each DataTemplate to target a different Notification derived class. Here's a link to one of my previous answers which is quite similar in concept. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15404164/1862333 Take a look at the ingoing and outgoing message classes and how the datatemplates work with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx):

---

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DocumentAnnouncmentTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DocumentCommentTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileTransferTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="GeneralAnnouncmentTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MeetingAnnouncmentTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MeetingCommentTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>

<local:FriendlyTypeTemplateSelector x:Key="FriendlyTypeTemplateSelector"
  DocumentAnnouncmentTemplate="{StaticResource DocumentAnnouncmentTemplate}"
  DocumentCommentTemplate="{StaticResource DocumentCommentTemplate}"
  FileTransferTemplate="{StaticResource FileTransferTemplate}"
  GeneralAnnouncmentTemplate="{StaticResource GeneralAnnouncmentTemplate}"
  MeetingAnnouncmentTemplate="{StaticResource MeetingAnnouncmentTemplate}"
  MeetingCommentTemplate="{StaticResource MeetingCommentTemplate}" />

...

<ListBox ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FriendlyTypeTemplateSelector}"
  ... />
```

**C# Code:**

```
public class FriendlyTypeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DocumentAnnouncmentTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DocumentCommentTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FileTransferTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate GeneralAnnouncmentTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate MeetingAnnouncmentTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate MeetingCommentTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var notification = item as Notification;

        if (notification != null)
        {
            switch (notification.FriendlyType)
            {
                case "Document Announcment":
                    return DocumentAnnouncmentTemplate;
                case "Document Comment":
                    return DocumentCommentTemplate;
                case "File Transfer Progress":
                    return FileTransferTemplate;
                case "Special Announcment":
                    return GeneralAnnouncmentTemplate;
                case "Meeting Announcment":
                    return MeetingAnnouncmentTemplate;
                case "Meeting Comment":
                    return MeetingCommentTemplate;
            }
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```